# Hide Category Name From bar Chart If Value Is Zero

Tags: excel, excel-charts

As you can see in the attached image, pie chart in Excel 2016 where I need to show the category name and values in the chart. The data typically have some zero values in it that I do not want to show on the chart.
I can hide the zero  by using custom number format 0;"" but it still leaves the category name and the  visible which makes the chart  messy to read.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAiOH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no straight forward approach to this scenario.

Please go through this link and pick out a suggestions that suits to your scenario.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-suppress-0-values-in-an-excel-chart/

Answer (score 0):

The only hack I found is to add an IF formula into the cells containing the category names...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).